# concatenation of integers using macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Just read this on a [forum](http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/377/give-12-and-36-write-a-function-which-return-an-integer-c-3612?show=393#a393). Can someone throw some light on this, why and how this works?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define merge(a, b) b##a
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d ", merge(12, 36));
    return 0;
}
```

on the other hand if we don't use macro, then compiler gives compilation error.

Comment: Just `##` operator doing what it was supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `##` is a form of MACRO replacement. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.10.3.3, the `##` operator

> If, in the replacement list of a function-like macro, a parameter is immediately preceded
>   or followed by a `##` preprocessing token, the parameter is replaced by the corresponding
>   argument’s preprocessing token sequence;

So, in your case, as per the MACRO definition,

```
#define merge(a, b) b##a
```

in your code

```
merge(12, 36)
```

looks like

```
3612
```

after the preprocessing stage.

FWIW, the complete statement, `printf("%d ", 3612);`, as simple as that.

Comment: @Prashant As you see, it's not. :-)